# Lookup ('deparse') list of names of objects read from csv files, then cbind them

Tags: r, dataframe

`temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")` outputs a vector ("filename1" "filename2" "etc").

I set it up so that the file `name.csv` equals the name of the data frame.

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

I am trying to automate combining the many separate dfs into one—using

```
cbind(`df1`, `df2`, `etc`). df1=filename1
```

How can I change `temp` into pasting a backslash `filename` backslash and also adding a comma between names?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. You don't need to change quotes around filenames to backslashes, just do the cbind.

Comment: Weird. At least on my side, I need to change the quotes to backlashes since dfs are in my Global Environment. But I also need to add commas to separate the dfs, which list.files does not include.

Comment: Please fix your title. As stands it makes it sound like just a string-formatting issue with choice of separator, which it totally isn't. But actually you want to lookup ('deparse') each of your variables, so you can cbind them.

Comment: @HusamHaj, it looks like you are doing several unnecessary steps here. There is no need to have the `assign`-loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your task is only about cbinding together multiple data.frames from multiple files. This can be done as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") 
df <- lapply(temp, function(x) read.csv(x)) %>% bind_cols
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `` backticks operator/ `deparse` function to access individual objects (dfs) and cbind them:

```
cbind( lapply(c(df1, df2, etc...), deparse) )
```

But why deal with individual object names in the first place, that's just 
making your life hard? Just read in the csv files and assign them to a list of dfs: `df[1], df[2], ....`